# SurfaceInkCanvas and ScatterView in combination?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pixelsense

I have the following layout:

```
<Grid Width="1024" Height="768" Background="{StaticResource WindowBackground}" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <s:ScatterView Name="hitter">
            <s:ScatterViewItem Orientation="0" Width="100" Height="100"></s:ScatterViewItem>
            <s:ScatterViewItem Orientation="0" Width="100" Height="100"></s:ScatterViewItem>
            <s:ScatterViewItem Orientation="0" Width="100" Height="100"></s:ScatterViewItem>
            <s:ScatterViewItem Orientation="0" Width="100" Height="100"></s:ScatterViewItem>
            <s:ScatterViewItem Orientation="0" Width="100" Height="100"></s:ScatterViewItem>
            <s:ScatterViewItem Orientation="0" Width="100" Height="100"></s:ScatterViewItem>
        </s:ScatterView>

            <s:SurfaceInkCanvas Grid.Row="0" Name="Gesture" s:Contacts.PreviewContactDown="Gesture_PreviewContactDown" s:Contacts.PreviewContactChanged="Gesture_PreviewContactChanged" s:Contacts.PreviewContactUp="Gesture_PreviewContactUp"></s:SurfaceInkCanvas>
        <StackPanel Margin="20" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <s:SurfaceTextBox Text="TemplateName" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="White" Width="200" Name="TemplateName"></s:SurfaceTextBox>
            <s:SurfaceButton Name="Add" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent" Content="Add new template" PreviewContactDown="Add_PreviewContactDown"></s:SurfaceButton>
            <TextBox Foreground="White" Background="Transparent" Margin="220,0,0,0" Name="ResultDisplay" Width="500"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Now the problem is that if I want to move my `ScatterViewItems`, the events are consumed by the `SurfaceInkCanvas` and a stroke is drawn.
That's why I tried to set the property `IsHitTestVisible` of `SurfaceInkCanvas` to `false`.
Then I can move the `ScatterviewItems`, but I can't draw any strokes anymore and the `SurfaceInkCanvas`.

How can I allow both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about you want the user to do differently to signal to your application that they are trying to manipulate the SVI vs. draw inside of it.

Common answers to this question are either:

To manipulate, the user will touch a visible 'frame' around the inkcanvas.  To implement this, just add padding to the SVI.

To ink, the user will tap a button to switch the item to "inking" mode.  To implement this, add a button the SVI which toggles IsEnabled for the inkcanvas.

Comment: Thanks Robert. This will work, but I'm looking for a intuitive way to implement that in my application. I use SurfaceInkCanvas to recognize gestures and to do specific actions based on that. The recognition works already, but now I'm not sure how to do that in combination with my application. If I always have a SurfaceInkCanvas at the top, I would have to disable/enable it whenever the user wants to add a gesture. This will work, but I can't really think of an easy way the users can indicate if he wants to make a gesture or to just manipulate other UI elements. Do you see my problem?